# accessing a vector from the back

Tags: c++, vector

Is there a way to access an element on a vector starting from the back? I want to access the second last element.currently I'm using the following to achieve that:

```
myVector[myVector.size() - 2]
```

but this seems slow and clunky, is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not likely to be any faster, but this might look nicer:

```
myVector.end()[-2]
```

Comment: Or `myVector.rbegin()[1]`.

Comment: @Pavel: I like that solution the best, it makes the most sense and looks very clean.

Comment: Note that Ben's point about this not really being any faster still applies, however.

Comment: Is this portable?  Is `std::vector::iterator` required to overload the index operator?  It will usually work, as `std::vector::iterator` is usually a typedef'd pointer.  But, is it guaranteed?

Comment: @Caspin: Yes.  `std::vector` provides random access iterators, and that's one of the properties of a random access iterator.

Answer (score 5):

Well you can always use vector::back(). If you want to iterate from the back, use the reverse_iterator :

```
vector<something>::reverse_iterator iter = v.rbegin();
iter++; //Iterates backwards
```

Vectors are made for fast random access, so your way is just fine too. Accessing a vector element at any index is an O(1) operation.

Comment: vector<something>::reverse_iterator iter = v.rbegin();

Answer (score 0):

Your way is perfectly valid and pretty fast except that you should check `myVector.size() > 1`.

Comment: Or i could do it like myvector.at(myVector.end - 2) and make it even slower.

Comment: `at` uses exceptions to indicate out-of-range error. I'd not use it in this simple case.